# Associative noncommutative hash function

Tags: hash

Is there a hash function with following properties?

- is associative
- is not commutative
- easily implementable on 32 bit integers: `int32 hash(int32, int32)`

If I am correct, such function allows achieving following goals

- calculate hash of concatenated string from hashes of substrings
- calculate hash concurrently
- calculate hash of list implemented on binary tree - including order, but excluding how tree is balanced

The best I found so far is multiplication of 4x4 matrix of bits, but thats awkward to implement and reduces space to 16bits.

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[Polynomial rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) could help:

- H(A1,...,An) = (H(A1,...,An-1) * Base + An) Mod P

It's easy to concat two results or substract prefix/suffix from result, as long as the length is known.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is associative and non-commutative.

You could try representing your hashes as matrices but this will result in a loss of information if they have **0** determinant (which is likely!).

So instead you should generate a [triangle matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) with a diagonal of **1**'s to ensure that you have a determinant of **1** (this guarantees that composition does not loose information).

Furthermore the composition of triangle matrices produces a new triangle matrix, making reading the composition the same as generation.

**Note: to use this method the length of your hash must be a triangle number!**

Comment: What do you mean by composition of matrices? Matrix multiplication (if so, wouldn't you run out or precision really fast?)?